# Performance impact of reverse relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I'm setting up my Models and I'm trying to avoid using ManyToMany Relationships.
I have this setup:

- Model: Human
- Some Humans (a small percentage) need to have M2M relationships with other Humans. Let's call this relationship "knows" (reverse relationship called "is_known_by").
- To avoid setting a ManyToManyField in Humans, I made a Model FamousHumans.
- FamousHumans are a special class of Human and have a OneToOneField(Human)
- They also have a ManyToManyField(Humans) to represent the "knows" relationship

Here is my question:
Since Django creates reverse relationships, I assume that all Humans will have a reverse "is_known_by" relationship to FamousHumans, so there is still a M2M relationship. Is there any performance benefit to my setup?

The dataset will be rather large and only a few Humans will need the M2M relationship. My main concern is performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unnecessarily complex.

There is no performance overhead to having a many-to-many relationship. This is represented by an intermediary table in the database; there's no actual field in the humans table. If an item doesn't have any m2m members, then no data is stored.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try to simplify everything

Comment: what about the join operation?